# Turn numeric vector into boolean matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector, boolean

I have a column vector in a *dataframe* and would like to turn it into a binary matrix so I can do matrix multiplication with it later on.

```
y_labels
1
4
4
3
```

desired output

```
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
```

In Octave I would do something like `y_matrix = (y_labels == [1 2 3 4])`. However, I can't figure out how to get this in R. Anybody know how?

Comment: Try `dummy::dummy(data.frame(myF = factor(df1$y_labels, levels = 1:4)))`

Comment: did you mean to write dummies::dummy(data.frame(myF = factor(df1$y_labels, levels = 1:4)))?

Comment: They are different packages, both should give similar results.

Comment: ok thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another option:

Start by creating a matrix of zeros:

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = max(df$y_labels))
```

Then insert 1s at the correct positions:

```
m[col(m) == df$y_labels] <- 1
```

The result is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    1
[3,]    0    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0    1    0
```

Comment: ah ok cool, it's a little bit similar to the way I would do it in octave. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `model.matrix` to change it to binary

```
model.matrix(~ -1 + factor(y_labels, levels = 1:4), df1)
```

---

or with `table`

```
with(df1, table(1:nrow(df1), factor(y_labels, levels = 1:4)))
#    1 2 3 4
#  1 1 0 0 0
#  2 0 0 0 1
#  3 0 0 0 1
#  4 0 0 1 0
```

---

Or more compactly

```
+(sapply(1:4, `==`, df1$y_labels))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    1
#[3,]    0    0    0    1
#[4,]    0    0    1    0
```

Comment: Great thanks! What does ~ -1 do? I got kinda confused there.

Comment: @zipline86  It is to remove the intercept column

Comment: great thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

How about (where `vec` is your numeric vector):

```
m <- matrix(0, length(vec), max(vec))
m[cbind(seq_along(vec), vec)] <- 1

#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    1
#[3,]    0    0    0    1
#[4,]    0    0    1    0
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a use case for OP, but matrix might not be square.

Comment: just a side note, op states that their input is a data.frame, not an atomic vector.

Comment: @docendodiscimus yes but `df$y_labels` in place of `vec`. The title says a numeric vector though.

Answer (score 1):

In base `R`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(y_labels = c(1,4,4,3))
t(sapply(df1$y_labels,function(x) c(rep(0,x-1),1,rep(0,max(df1$y_labels)-x))))
```

or

```
t(sapply(df1$y_labels,function(x) `[<-`(numeric(max(df1$y_labels)),x,1)))
```

output:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    1
# [3,]    0    0    0    1
# [4,]    0    0    1    0
```